# How do I display an integer in a textbox in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have searched DreamInCode and even this site but I have not found an answer.
I am very new to programming and I guess this is just so simple I should know, but I don't. In Visual Basic how do I make a `TextBox` display an `Integer`. For example:

```
Private Sub timer1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim GDP As Integer
    GDP = 125000
    PictureBox1 = GDP
End Sub
```

It gives me this error

> Value of type 'integer' cannot be converted to picture box

I have seen answers to similar problems in c# and in more complex cases but none for mine can anyone help?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  Is your questions about `TextBox` (title) or `PictureBox` (post body)?  Either way, controls are objects, not just text or integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `TextBox` represents a control that displays plain text, while `PictureBox` control displays an image (raster) object. In this particular case you need `TextBox` control to display your `GDP` value, and you need to use it like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = GDP.ToString
```

...since you need your integer `GDP` value converted to string beforehand.